# copy() makes empty files

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, copy

I'm trying to use copy() to copy WooCommerce templates into another folder (the theme folder).

The files get copied but are empty.

I'm using Wamp64 on localhost.

Anyone knows why?

EDIT1
This is how I create the folders where the copies are supposed to go

```
mkdir(self::$wcCustomDir . '/emails', 0777, true);
```

Not sure if it's a permission issue.

Comment: copy() — Copies file only not the directories.

Comment: have you checked file/folder permissions ?

Comment: @Calimero Just edited question, think it will help

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's my bad. Didn't know that copy() created the files even if they couldn't find them in the first directory. Pretty strange. Tried with the full url and everything works.